# C# Can't connect to self hosted web api from other device

Tags: c#, .net, webserver

I have a C# self hosted web api (Console Application .NET Framework). I can check api from localhost but i can't connect to web api from other device such as phone or other desktop. I tried 192.168.X.X:PORT but it was unsuccessful.

I noticed that if you turn off the Firewall, then when you try to make a request to the API from another device, the request fails with error:
"Bad Request - Invalid Hostname.
HTTP Error 400. The request hostname is invalid."
If I enable Firewall, then the request will take a long, long time.

Comment: Have you tried disabling windows' firewall and trying again?

Comment: Yes, i tried. Also i checked remote access for Spring Java and it was successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](https://andrewlock.net/5-ways-to-set-the-urls-for-an-aspnetcore-app/) might help you.

The problem is that by default, the binding is targeting only `localhost:PORT`. If you bind to `0.0.0.0:PORT` (and allow the port on you firewall) you'll be able to access from another machine.

You can either configure it by `UseUrls()`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
    }

    public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
        Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
            .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
            {
                webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
                webBuilder.UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:5000", "https://0.0.0.0:5001");
            });
}
```

or when running the application

```
$> ./myApp --urls=http://0.0.0.0:5000
```

Comment: Thanks! My problem was a firewall and a host bunding? so i change localhost to '*'.

Comment: I didn't recall if '*' really works. My apps here are configured with '0.0.0.0'. Good to know that it does :)

Comment: i have the same issue and when i used "http://*:9008/" as the base URL, it worked well with all the devices on the same network, but it's not working with devices from outside the network, can anyone help, please?

Comment: What do you mean 'outside the network'? If you're trying to access it from a public network e.g. from the internet hosting the application in your home network, you need to configure NAT, Port Redirect and/or a firewall rule in your network. If you do access the application from another device in your network, then the configuration is correct. Anything beyond depends on the configuration of your own private network.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do new Query from firewall setting  or disabling it

insert port like 1433 in the serveces setting of sql servce clint and enabling it

Answer (score 0):

If anyone stumbles upon this answer I hope it helps you.

I have api that was previously starting at *localhost:5131*, and I could get to this IP from my virtual device with app I am developing (after setting up *10.0.2.2* as IP to connect to from my android app).

But when I tried connecting from the android app from my Xiaomi phone, I couldn't connect to the api. My PC's DHCP assigned IP was *192.168.100.207* and I could ping it from the phone but not connect to api with port. For this I even created inbound and outbound rules in firewall and eventually disabled firewall.

What helped me was changing the **applicationUrl** in my launchSettings.json file. It was *localhost:5131* now its *192.168.100.207:5131* Now my api is served at *192.168.100.207:5131/api/xxx* and is reachable from the android app running on Xiaomi phone. Hope this helps someone.